# Why every() method returns false

Tags: javascript

```
const c = [2, 4]
c.every(el => {12%el == 0})
```

Can someone explain why every() returns false?

Comment: Because you don't return anything from the function. Remove the curly brackets.

Comment: Or, rather, you implicitly return undefined which is false-y.

Answer (score 1):

Your function return nothing

use:

```js
c.every(el => {
  return 12 % el == 0;
});
```

or

```js
c.every(el => (12 % el == 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Non zero values are treated as True and zero/no value (when not defined ) are false. In case of absence of explicit return, it is no value that implicit typecasted to false.